# what is more efficient: applying text transformations to a corpora or df

Tags: r, memory-management, dplyr, tm

I have a `df` with about 100k rows with `texts` and `doc_id` as columns which I want to use for a text analysis.

In order to perform some text transformations I generate a wordCorpus:

```
df %>%  data.frame(.) %>%  DataframeSource(.) %>% Corpus(.) -> wordCorpus
```

Standard transformations such as `tolower` works well:

```
wordCorpus<- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer(wordCorpus))
```

However, if I apply a bit a more complex transformation, I run out of memory (although I have 32GB RAM).

```
memory.limit(size=100000)
complex <- content_transformer(function(x) gsubfn("(\\d+)(-| - | bis | jusqu'à )(\\d+)", ~ paste(seq(..1, ..3), collapse = " "), x))
wordCorpus<- tm_map(wordCorpus,complex)
```

Would it be more efficient to perform the transformations on the `df` itself?

something like: `df %>% group_by(doc_id) %>% mutate(texts=gsubfn("(\\d+)(-| - | bis | jusqu'à )(\\d+)", ~ paste(seq(..1, ..3), collapse = " "), .)`

Or is there a better way to get the transformations done with less memory usage?